# Flex/BlazeDS Error missing property

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, blazeds

I have this error when running my application on debug mode :

> ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property root on MyClass.

The problem is that MyClass doesn't contain any root property and i don't know how it get it, 
I have isRoot property at the Java Class with setRoot setter and isRoot methods,

at the flex side i have isRoot as public without getter and setter.... could the problem be just convention names compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flex property name must be `root` instead of `isRoot`.

BlazeDS is using the [*Java Beans naming convention*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean#JavaBean_conventions). For more informations read the [BlazeDS Developer Guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide) / [**Serializing between ActionScript and Java**](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/serialize_data_3.html#296603):

> BlazeDS uses the standard Java class,
>   java.beans.Introspector, to get
>   property descriptors for a Java bean
>   class. It also uses reflection to
>   gather public fields on a class. It
>   uses bean properties in preference to
>   fields. The Java and ActionScript
>   property names should match.